# How to split this array up into separate elements / arrays to use in Table in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have the following code which I believe splits my array (dict) up into 3 sections using `for (_ , value) in dict {` .

```
      let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]
                    print (json!)

                    if let dict = json?["playerForm"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
                        print ("step 1")

                        for (_ , value) in dict {
                            if let arr = value as? [[String:Any]] {
                                print(arr)
                               self.leagueForm = arr.flatMap { Form($0) }

                                for i in 0..<self.leagueForm.count {

                                     let form = self.leagueForm[i]
                                     self.formGuide.append(form.player_result!)

                                }
                                print ("break")

                            }
                        }


                        print (self.formGuide)
                    }
```

My hope is that within self.leagueForm there are 3 elements containing data for each player.

This data is then put into this custom class:

```
struct Form {
    var player_result: String?
    var player_name: String?
    var result_date: String?
    var result_id: String?

    init(_ dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        self.player_result = dictionary["result"] as? String ?? ""
        self.player_name = dictionary["name"]  as? String ?? ""
        result_date = dictionary["date"]  as? String ?? ""
        result_id = String(dictionary["results_id"]  as? Int ?? 0)

    }
}

var leagueForm = [Form]()
```

When I `print (arr)` it prints the full array.

My aim is to have 3 sets of data within the custom class, 1 for each player.  You can see the breaks for each player in the screenshot below.

[image]

In the last line of this image you see that the Form for each player has been added to the one element.

Want I want is something like the following:

```
[name: G , results: "W", "D", "W", "D", "W", "W", "D", "L"] 
[name: Dicky, results: "L", "L", "D", "W", "L", "W", "W", "W"]
[name: Sultan, results: "W", "W", "D", "L", "L", "L", "D", "L"]
```

That I can then pass into a table to display the results.

How do I achieve this?  Or how can I test my custom class to see where I'm at so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this way

```
var arrResult : [String] = []
let arrMainData = [["name":"ABC","result":"result1"],["name":"ABC","result":"result2"],["name":"ABC","result":"result3"]]

let name : String! = arrMainData[arrMainData.count-1]["name"]

for index in 0...arrMainData.count-1{
    arrResult.append(arrMainData[index]["result"]!)
}

let myArr : [String: AnyObject] = ["name" : name,"arrResult":arrResult]
print(myArr)
```

result should be like [name: ABC , results:["result1","result2","result3"]]

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer @Sunil but I don't know how to apply your answer to my situation.

Comment: @RDowns implement in struct Form's init method

Comment: inside `init(_ dictionary: [String : Any]) {  } ` ?  or inside `for i in 0..<self.leagueForm.count {`  ?

Comment: Xcode is requesting I make an edit to:   `let myArr : [String: AnyObject] = ["name" : name as AnyObject,"arrResult":arrResult as AnyObject]`

Is this correct?

Comment: still not worked out how to get this working with my code above

Comment: In your code you have hardcoded for 3 sets of results - in my code i gave the example of 3 players but that is why I use a foreach loop because the number of players  will differ.  Does your code account for this?

Answer (score 0):

`for each` is a more swifty way of implementing a for loop, but the way Sunil has implemented it is functionally identical.  One thing you can simplify is the way you're implementing your for each loop - if you don't need the index, don't include it at all - you don't need to replace it with `_`

Here's how you might rewrite the leagueForm section of your code

```
for value in dict {
    if let arr = value as? [[String:Any]] {
        print(arr)
        self.leagueForm = arr.flatMap { Form($0) }

        for form in self.leagueForm {
            self.formGuide.append(form.player_result!)
        }
        print ("break")

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, do I put that inside of my ` for i in 0..<self.leagueForm.count {` loop?