# Failing to iterate through this dictionary and organise into a custom Struct

Tags: php, ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I have this snippet of code that I am using to iterate the array `playerForm`.

`playerForm` contains a number of arrays for each player in the array, and contains the form for each player.

i.e

```
["playerForm": {
1 =     (
            {
        date = "2017-01-31";
        name = Dicky;
        result = L;
        "results_id" = 42;
    },
            {
        date = "2017-01-26";
        name = Dicky;
        result = L;
        "results_id" = 41;
    }
  );
2 =     (
            {
        date = "2017-01-25";
        name = G;
        result = W;
        "results_id" = 38;
    },
            {
        date = "2017-01-25";
        name = G;
        result = D;
        "results_id" = 40;
    }
3 =     (
            {
        date = "2017-01-31";
        name = Sultan;
        result = W;
        "results_id" = 42;
    },
            {
        date = "2017-01-26";
        name = Sultan;
        result = W;
        "results_id" = 41;
    }
    );
    }]
```

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
  let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]
                    print (json!)

                    if let dict = json?["playerForm"] as? [String:Any] {

                        print ("step 1")

                        for value in dict {
                            if let arr = value as? [[String:Any]] {
                                print(arr)
                                self.leagueForm = arr.flatMap { Form($0) }

                                for form in self.leagueForm {
                                    self.formGuide.append(form.player_result!)
                                }
                                print ("break")

                            }
                        }


                        print (self.formGuide)
                    }
```

And this is my custom Struct to organise the data;

```
 struct Form {
    var player_result: String?
    var player_name: String?
    var result_date: String?
    var result_id: String?

    init(_ dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        self.player_result = dictionary["result"] as? String ?? ""
        self.player_name = dictionary["name"]  as? String ?? ""
        result_date = dictionary["date"]  as? String ?? ""
        result_id = String(dictionary["results_id"]  as? Int ?? 0)


    }
}

var leagueForm = [Form]()
```

However, I am getting the warning: `Cast from '(key: String, value: AnyObject)' to unrelated type [[String : Any]] always fails`.

This is my PHP script that provides the initial array:

```
$noPlayers = count($communityPlayersIds); //
$playerForm = array();
$playerForm = $dao->getCommunityForm($communityId, $noPlayers, $communityPlayersIds);

public function getCommunityForm($communityId, $noPlayers, $communityPlayersIds){
$sql = " SELECT IF(player1_id=?, player1_result, player2_result) AS result, IF(player1_id=?, player1_name, player2_name) AS name, date, results_id FROM `results` WHERE (player1_id=? OR player2_id=?) AND community_id=? ORDER BY date DESC Limit 8";
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
$i = 0;
foreach ($communityPlayersIds as $cPI) {
    $i++;
    $stmt->bind_param("iiiii", $cPI, $cPI, $cPI, $cPI, $communityId);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($result = $stmt->get_result()) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
             $returnValue[$i][] = $row;
             }
        }
    }return $returnValue;
}

echo json_encode (array('playerForm' => $playerForm ));
```

So this 1,2,3 in the example above is how I have indexed the returned results from the MySQL.  I did this as a way to separate the data so I could structure it in Swift

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you show the JSON printed out through swift instead of PHP?

Comment: Hi @johnslay that is the JSON printed through Swift...

Comment: OK, and is 'step 1' being printed out or is it not able to cast and enter scope to print that out?

Comment: yes step 1 prints

Comment: inside that for loop, i don't think it should be [[String: Any]], should just be [String: Any]

Comment: If i do that I still get the 'unrelated type always fails' warning, and a 'cannot covert value of type...to expect type' failure on the self.leagueForm = arr.flatMap { Form($0) }  line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135709/discussion-between-johnslay-and-rdowns).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't unwrap your JSON properly. `json["playerForm"]` is an array of dictionaries, not a dictionary. Try this:

```
let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.allowFragments]) as! [String: Any]
var leagueForm = [Form]()

if let forms = json["playerForm"] as? [[String: Any]] {
    leagueForm = forms.flatMap { Form($0) }
}
```

---

*I assume that this is your sample JSON:*

```
{
    "playerForm": [
        {"result": "L", "name": "Dicky", "date": "2017-02-10", "results_id": 48},
        {"result": "L", "name": "Dicky", "date": "2017-02-10", "results_id": 47},
        {"result": "L", "name": "Dicky", "date": "2017-02-09", "results_id": 44},
        {"result": "L", "name": "Dicky", "date": "2017-01-16", "results_id": 32},
        {"result": "D", "name": "Dicky", "date": "2016-12‌​-12", "results_id": 4},
        {"result": "W", "name": "Dicky", "date": "2016-12-12", "results_id": 6},
        {"result": "W", "name": "Dicky", "date": "2016-12-12", "results_id": 8}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is at this line of code

```
if let arr = value as? [[String:Any]] {
```

Looking at your JSON file I can see your json object is of this format:

```
["playerForm": {
1 =     (
            {
        date = "2017-01-31";
        name = Dicky;
        result = L;
        "results_id" = 42;
    },
            {
        date = "2017-01-26";
        name = Dicky;
        result = L;
        "results_id" = 41;
    }
  );...
```

So your json root object is a [String : Any] dictionary, which you are doing correctly. The dictionary only has one (key,value) pair, with the key 'PlayerForm'. After that you are assuming that the value of that pair is of the type [[String:Any]], which would be an array of arrays of dictionaries, which i don't think it is :) 
I think that this part:

```
2 =     (
            {
```

is kinda faulty from the JSON file, I am not quite sure as to what the "2=" should be standing for, but it's not an array, as arrays do not contain a key, like the "1,2,3...".

I would suggest casting the value to something else, maybe try

something  = value as? [String: Any]

And if that works then you can cast the value inside that dictionary to NSArray for iteration.

Just play around with the cast there for a while :)

Comment: Thankyou @Florens.  I have provided you with my PHP functions and MySQL Query to show you what the 1,2,3 stands for.  Maybe this is where I have been going wrong?

Comment: I am sorry I know little about PHP. Have you tried casting the value to something else, other than [[String: Any]]?

Comment: yeah i get a similar warning.  Thanks for looking anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `value in dict` swift returns two pieces of information: a key and a value. Thus, generally the more accepted approach is to do something like this:

```
for (key, value) in dict ...
```

If you are predicting that the value for each dictionary entry is going to be of type `[[String: Any]]` then I would suggest doing something like this:

```
for (_, value) in dict {
    if let dictValue = value as? [[String:Any]] {
        //do the rest with this value
    }

}
```

Note, you can put an underscore for the key variable name since you aren't going to be using it, and thus you don't need to store it in memory.

Of course, this does not guarantee that you code will work now, but it should solve this specific problem.

Comment: Hi @BenjaminLowry, thanks for your answer - funnily enough that was how I originally had it structured, but I was still unable to achieve my aim of structuring the data in Swift.  I posted a question to Stack Overflow and followed a solution to change to this code.  I have updated the question with more information. Cheers

Comment: @RDowns Okay I looked at your updated question, but even if your JSON is incorrectly formatted that doesn't really change the fact that you are having this casting issue. I just looked at your other SO question, and even the answerer suggested you to do it this way. What's the problem when you implement this solution?

Comment: That got me to a certain point, but I was having trouble splitting up the array.  I posted this question: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42039859/how-to-split-this-array-up-into-separate-elements-arrays-to-use-in-table-in-sw/42095029?noredirect=1#comment71360571_42095029

And then bottom answer suggested I changed that piece of code - which is where I am now.